# JSOUP is removing nested <HTML> tag in <XML> document

Tags: html, xml, jsoup

I know `JSOUP` is used to generate proper `HTML documents`.
However a colleague is also using it to generate an XML payload that needs to include an HTML document.

```
d.appendElement(PConstants.CONTENT_TAG).attr("id", PConstants.PCONTENT_TAG_ID).html(getAlfrescoContent().getAlfContentContentStr());
```

`getAlfContentContentStr` returns a document that is wrapped in `<HTML>` tags. However these tags are removed in the `.html()` element method (oh `jsoup`).

How do I avoid this? I was thinking of maybe using `<data-custom-html>` tags and then replacing these with `<html>` in the final string.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a pre-fix to the specific tags, and then replacing the pre-fix away from the final string.